# What does "'LBLMY" mean on the side of a railcar?

Tags: rail

In this photo, what does `'LBLMY` signify? Seeing it directly under the capacity, and 5000 pounds lower, I'm guessing it's a "limited capacity" of some sort. But I can't come up with anything that would abbreviate to `'LBLMY`.

The only things I've found while searching for "lblmy" look like OCR errors.

[image: Railcar label]

Comment: Where did this photo come from? I ask because there are a bunch of similar examples available online. Some have slightly different letters that make more sense. Some are also from model trains.

Comment: @hazzey It's a photo of a static display in the cafeteria in the Union Pacific headquarters in Omaha, Nebraska. It looks like it is actual panels from a retired car, but maybe it was just faked up to look like that. In which case, perhaps the artist or painter deviated from the original when creating this display.

Comment: This http://speedwitchmedia.com/product/d161-pacific-fruit-express-r-30-9-with-1948-black-white-sp-medallionup-shield/ is apparently the same design but has "LDLMT" (which presumably means "load limit".

Comment: @alephzero  Aha! Nice find. So it seems likely that the reproduction was from a poor quality photo, and `*LD.LMT.` got interpreted, either by a human or by OCR, as `'LBLMY`. If you'll write it up as an answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: Odds are based on the diagonal pseudo rivets, it's an artist representation.  Most train cars have two abbreviations LD LMT - Load Limit (Loaded) and LT WT - Light Weight (Unloaded).  T sort of looks like a Y.